# How to authenticate Elasticsearch with multiple users

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

We are trying create manage Elastic above AWS separate tenant (customer) and assign each tenant to a different index.

Each customer will have their user name/password or similar like token, etc.

We setup a managed ES on AWS and did integration with native Elastic sdk HighRestClient

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works fine, all our actions performed from Java code like creating index/manage/searches, etc.

This piece of code simulates the basic auth as described here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/_basic_authentication.html

```java
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(settings.getEsUserName(), settings.getEsUserPass()));
restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(builder -> builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
```

Now we creating different index on each customer which is OK, but the problem is that now all our customers will have the same username/password.

Is it possible somehow to do this on multiple users, have multiple username/password?

So each user can interact only with his index authenticated with password.

I saw this case - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-walkthrough-basic

As I understand from reading they are talking about multi tenancy on Kibana users.

Am I missing something, is it possible to achieve our goal in different ways?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two concepts here. You can refer to the below concepts and decide which use case suits you best.

**Fine grained access control** provides you with internal database authentication mechanism by which you can create multiple users (having their own username/password) and attach roles/action groups to these users - so each user can have different permissions. Thereafter, each customer can be provided with a different username/password.

**Tenants** is a concept existing in Kibana system (with above security enabled), where a tenant can be used to store kibana related objects such as dashboards and visualisations. There are two defaults tenants - `global` which is shared between all users, and `private` tenant which is exclusive to each customer. You can create your own custom tenant, and configure it to be accessed by a group of users, so that these users can share kibana related objects.

More on tenants here: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security/access-control/multi-tenancy/